# QSUB: Specify output and error files for each task in Job Array

Tags: bash, cluster-computing, qsub, sungridengine

Hopefully this is not a dublicate and also not just a problem of our cluster's configuration...

I am submitting a job array to a cluster using `qsub` with the following command:

```
qsub -q QUEUE -N JOBNAME -t 1:10 -e ${ERRFILE}_$SGE_TASK_ID /path/to/script.sh
```

where

```
ERRFILE=/home/USER/somedir/errors.
```

The idea is to specify an error file (also analogously the output file) that also contains the task ID from within the job array.

So far I have learned that the line

```
#$ -e ${ERRFILE}_$SGE_TASK_ID
```

inside the script.sh, does not work, because it is a comment and not evaluated by bash. My first line does not work however because `$SGE_TASK_ID` is only set AFTER the job is submitted.
I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479277/pbspro-qsub-output-error-file-directed-to-path-with-jobid-in-name) that escaping the evaluation of `$SGE_TASK_ID` (in that link it's PBS' `$PBS_JOBID`, but a similar problem) should work, but when I tried

```
qsub -q QUEUE -N JOBNAME -t 1:10 -e ${ERRFILE}_\$SGE_TASK_ID /path/to/script.sh
```

it did not work as expected.

Am I missing something obvious? Is it possible to use `$SGE_TASK_ID` in the name of an error file (the automatic naming of error files does that, but I want to specify the directory and if possible the name, too)?

Some additional remarks:

- I am using the `-cwd` option for `qsub` inside script.sh, but that is NOT where I want my error files to be stored.
- I have next to no control over how the cluster works and no root access (wouldn't know what I could need it for in this context but anyway...).
- Apparently our cluster does not use PBS.
- Yes my scripts are all executable and where applicable started with `#!/bin/bash` (I also specified the use of bash with the `-S /bin/bash` option for qsub).
- There seems to be a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096959/how-to-specify-error-log-file-and-output-file-in-qsub), but I am not quite sure how that works and it also appears to be using PBS. If that answer DOES apply to my question and I misunderstood it, please let me know.

I would appreciate any hint into the right direction.
Thank You!

Comment: what if you have it on the top of the submission script? I tried this but it doesn't work: `#PBS -e="experiment_output_job.%j.%N.out"
#PBS -o="experiment_output_job.%j.%N.out"`

Comment: related: https://community.openpbs.org/t/how-to-include-the-job-id-and-other-info-in-the-output-file-for-qsub/2369 `How to include the job id and other info in the output file for qsub?`

Comment: @CharlieParker Not sure if it helps, but have a look here: https://ask.cyberinfrastructure.org/t/can-pbs-use-variables-in-the-name-of-the-output-file/1238

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I didn't know this either, but it looks like Grid Engine has something called "pseudo environment variables" like `$TASK_ID` for this purpose. This should work:

```
qsub -q QUEUE -N JOBNAME -t 1:10 -e ${ERRFILE}_\$TASK_ID /path/to/script.sh
```

From the [man page](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html):

> ```
>  -e [[hostname]:]path,...
>       ...
>
>       If the  pathname  contains  certain  pseudo
>       environment  variables, their value will be expanded at
>       runtime of the job and will be used to  constitute  the
>       standard  error  stream path name. The following pseudo
>       environment variables are supported currently:
>
>       $HOME       home directory on execution machine
>       $USER       user ID of job owner
>       $JOB_ID     current job ID
>       $JOB_NAME   current job name (see -N option)
>       $HOSTNAME   name of the execution host
>       $TASK_ID    array job task index number
> ```

Comment: This did in fact work. Thanks a lot. I failed to specifically look at the description of the `-e` option. Also thanks for adding the tag. I looked for SGE, but couldn't find it.
If anyone else ever needs this, beware that the \ (backslash), that leekaiinthesky correctly used in the answer (`\$TASK_ID`) is indeed necessary, despite the man page not mentioning that.

Comment: The backslash is also necessary when running qsub with a command script, e.g. `#$ -o logs/job.\$TASK_ID.log`

Comment: what if you have it on the top of the submission script? I tried this but it doesn't work: `#PBS -e="experiment_output_job.%j.%N.out"
#PBS -o="experiment_output_job.%j.%N.out"`